# Is StringBuilder slow enough that I should cache its result?

Tags: java, caching, redis, stringbuilder

I'm writing some code to access Redis from Java, and as such I need to create a lot of Strings as keys. These keys have a pattern, of course, and I'll be regenerating the same keys for the same access repeatedly.

I'm considering implementing a cache for the generated keys (based on the DAO parameters), but even given the speed of a cache, I'm wondering if the speedup is worth the complexity.

The keys are comprised of a UUID concatenated with a 3-7 character string. Is StringBuilder slow enough in this scenario to warrant a cache?

Comment: Profiling is the only way to find out for sure :)

Comment: If you end up creating many of the same strings dynamically, look into [String interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) - `String#intern()`

Comment: If it's a single concatenation of reasonably small strings, cash lookup will certainly by slower.

Comment: @Shakedown - how is interning going to help with this?

Comment: @Shakedown - Interning doesn't make it any easier to look up a string given component data. It's also not a caching mechanism _per se_; it's a mechanism to ensure that there is only one copy of each distinct interned string value. (Thus, one can use `==` to compare compile-time string constants, even across compilation units.) I see no way that it helps here.

Comment: @TedHopp: True, I see what you're saying. Well at least interning is something to be aware of.

Comment: Appreciate the info everyone - agreed that profiling makes the most sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only profiling can tell you for sure, but if you're caching these you have to have some way to get them from the cache, and that likely will have at least as much overhead as just using StringBuilder.

StringBuilder is used internally when doing things like

```
String result = strPart1 + strPart2;
```

Comment: Even profiling may not really tell you the answer. You might see a small performance gain, but you by adding a lot of long lived objects then you're going to make garbage collection more expensive, and that's much harder to figure out.

Comment: @Bill - You can use the profiling another way.  Run the application for a long time, and just measure what percentage of the application's time is spent in the StringBuffer calls that the OP is concerned about.  If the percentage is small, then the *potential* for performance gain by caching is likewise small.  From that you can decide whether it is worth the effort trying to optimize ...

Comment: Yes that's correct. However, its hard to see what the effect is on GC with a profiler.

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone else is saying, profile. If the UUID is fixed, you can speed things up a bit as follows:

```
public class KeyGenerator {
    private final StringBuilder sb;
    private final int uidLen;

    public KeyGenerator(String uid) {
        sb = new StringBuilder(uid);
        uidLen = uid.length();
    }

    public String getKey(String suffix) {
        sb.setLength(uidLen);
        sb.append(suffix);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

This saves constructing a new StringBuilder and appending the uid every time you need a key. It's also a bit simpler than a cache.

Comment: Object instantiation in Java is _very_ fast.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL - everything OP is talking about is fast; we're taking relative speed-ups. It's not just object instantiation being saved, but also copying the UID characters into the StringBuilder every time. Not to mention the garbage collection that's avoided by not creating a new StringBuilder for every key. (I don't know what the key generation rate is, but if OP is concerned about this, it's probably quite high.)

Comment: @TedHopp - *"probably quite high"* ... assuming that the OP's intuition is correct.  He should really profile first.

Comment: @StephenC - Agreed. If it isn't high, then this is really a tempest in a teapot.